# Excel VBA using Find to update data in different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro that will allow me to compare data in two worksheets and update based on any differences (updates, insertions, deletions, etc.). This what I have so far - but it keeps getting caught on the line that calls Find. I've read a bunch of tutorials on how to do this, but haven't been able to figure out how to call it between worksheets and have it work correctly. Here's my code:

```
Sub Process()
    'loop through Intermediate sheet
    Dim DataRange As Range, UpdateRange As Range, orig As Range, nov As Range
    Dim lastIntRow As Long, lastDocRow As Long, firstEmptyRow As Long
    lastIntRow = Sheets("Intermediate").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    lastDocRow = Sheets("Document Library").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set DataRange = Sheets("Intermediate").Range(Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(lastIntRow, 1))
    Set UpdateRange = Sheets("Document Library").Range(Sheets("Document Library").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Document Library").Cells(lastDocRow, 1))
    For Each orig In DataRange
        Set nov = UpdateRange.Find(What:=orig)
            If nov Is Nothing Then
                firstEmptyRow = lastDocRow + 1
                Sheets("Document Library").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1).Value = orig.Value
                Sheets("Document Library").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 2).Value = Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(orig.Row, 2).Value
                Sheets("Document Library").Cells(firstEmptyRow, 3).Value = Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(orig.Row, 3).Value
            Else:
                Sheets("Document Library").Cells(nov.Row, 2).Value = Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(orig.Row, 2).Value
                Sheets("Document Library").Cells(nov.Row, 3).Value = Sheets("Intermediate").Cells(orig.Row, 3).Value
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be very appreciated. I'm really not sure how to do this correctly, and I feel like it's just getting more and more convoluted. Thank you!

Comment: Would be helpful if you were more specific about "keeps getting caught". What's the error message?

Comment: If I create a `Workbook` with the two sheets mentioned in the code and some text in the first column of each, I can run your code without any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Process()
    'loop through Intermediate sheet
    Dim DataRange As Range, UpdateRange As Range, orig As Range, nov As Range
    Dim lastIntRow As Long, lastDocRow As Long, firstEmptyRow As Long
    Dim shtInt As Worksheet, shtDoc As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range

    'using sheet variables de-clutters your code...
    Set shtInt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Intermediate")
    Set shtDoc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Document Library")

    lastIntRow = shtInt.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    lastDocRow = shtDoc.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    firstEmptyRow = lastDocRow + 1 'outside your loop!

    Set DataRange = shtInt.Range(shtInt.Cells(2, 1), shtInt.Cells(lastIntRow, 1))
    Set UpdateRange = shtDoc.Range(shtDoc.Cells(2, 1), shtDoc.Cells(lastDocRow, 1))

    For Each orig In DataRange.Cells

        'be more explicit with "Find()"
        Set nov = UpdateRange.Find(What:=orig, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If nov Is Nothing Then
            Set rw = shtDoc.Rows(firstEmptyRow)
            firstEmptyRow = firstEmptyRow + 1 'set next empty...
            rw.Cells(1).Value = orig.Value
        Else
            Set rw = nov.EntireRow
        End If

        rw.Cells(2).Value = orig.Offset(0, 1).Value
        rw.Cells(3).Value = orig.Offset(0, 2).Value

    Next
End Sub
```